# Change default text editor for crontab to vim

Tags: ubuntu, bash, text-editors

I'm using ubuntu 9.10 and the default text editor is nano, which i hate.  (doesn't everyone?)

Normally it's not a problem as i just vi or gedit everything but `crontab -e` is opening with nano.  I tried changing it to vim using `sudo update-alternatives --config editor` and selecting option 3 ("/usr/bin/vim.basic").  This has changed it for sudo and non-sudo alike.  But `crontab -e` still opens nano.  Any ideas?  max

Answer (score 164, accepted):

The `crontab -e` command will check the environment variables `$EDITOR` and `$VISUAL` for an override of the default text editor, so...

```
export VISUAL=vim
```

or

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Remember if you are editing another users's crontab, use `sudo -E crontab -e` where `sudo -E` specifies use your env vars.

Answer (score 113):

In ubuntu, try run: `select-editor`, which interactively creates `~/.selected_editor`:

```
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim.basic"
```

Comment: i tried this (under sudo and my user) and whatever option i changed, when i called it again it was still on nano.  Fixed it anyway with EDITOR env var but thought i'd better mention it anyway.  Cheers

Comment: Above answers didn't work...this does.

Comment: Yup, this changes ~/.sensible_editor used by /usr/bin/sensible-editor.  It seems that in the absence of the environment variables specifying the editor, crontab runs sensible-editor not editor as the former allows per-user configuration.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, running select-editor will not show the previously made selection, which is stored in ~/.sensible_editor.

Comment: @eelghEEz - Do you mean `~/.selected_editor`? That's what's on my system and what I've seen elsewhere.

Comment: works for debian too

Answer (score 27):

If you hate `nano` so much you can just uninstall it:

```
sudo apt-get remove nano
```

`crontab` should then just default to the next `EDITOR` (for me it was `vim.basic`).

Comment: We run our cron jobs with super-user account, but login to a dev account. So from dev account I need to do `sudo crontab -e`. I set `export EDITOR=vim` in both super-user's and the dev account's .bashrc, but `sudo crontab -e` was still opening up in nano. After uninstalling nano, it opens vim. Thanks!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.  Tried 4-5 things before this :)

Comment: This is by far the best solution if, as the OP implies, you never need nano. Not sure why it didn't occur to me before - probably that I didn't realise crontab would just default to the next available editor! Awesome

Answer (score 15):

From `man crontab`:

```
The -e option is used to edit the  current  crontab  using  the  editor
specified  by  the  VISUAL  or EDITOR environment variables.  After you
exit from the editor, the modified crontab will be installed  automati‐
cally.  If  neither  of  the environment variables is defined, then the
default editor /usr/bin/editor is used.
```

Add to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

Answer (score 5):

```
export EDITOR=vi && crontab -e
```

works on debian squeeze

Comment: A little explanation would go a long way.

Comment: this sets the EDITOR environment variable and subsequently edits the crontab file, `EDITOR=vim crontab -e` will work as well, but only one time.

Answer (score 5):

The better choice is to set alternative of editor (not just one user) :

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/vim 100
```

Comment: Why is it better to change the setting for other users, who did not asked for the change?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I can not comment or vote.

On Ubuntu the configuration file is called `~/.selected_editor`

With the following command you can select the **default editor** again:

```
$ select-editor
```

Removing the file in your home directory also works.

```
$ rm ~/.selected_editor
```

Only setting the variables `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR` will work but is only persistent if you write it to a script which is executed in your environment.

Add to your rc file

```
$ echo "export VISUAL=/usr/bin/vi" >> ~/.bashrc
```

But i wouldn't recommend to use the last solution.

Comment: If you don't recommend it why did you provide it?

Comment: Just for completion and because other people may prefer that way.

Answer (score 0):

You should best remove the `~/.sensible_editor` file and then running `crontab -e` will prompt you to choose the preferred editor.
 From then on your preference will be remembered in the `~/.sensible_editor` file.

Comment: not sure why this was down voted it is exactly what I need and worked perfectly.

Comment: Ubuntu does not seem to know `emacsclient`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to get rid of the product you don't want in its entirety.
All other config changes would be automatical.

`apt-get install vim -y && apt-get remove nano -y`

Answer (score 0):

The first answer worked for me, but I had to do this after saving changes in
~/.bashrc

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

That way you refresh your configuration.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Answer (score -1):

**for Debian, use :**

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor command
```

**and**

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------
06  * 0          /bin/nano            40       
07  1            /bin/nano            40       
08  2            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        
09  3            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10
```

select '2'  and press enter. Got it!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. The OP already tried this (it's in the question) and it did not fix his problem.

Answer (score -1):

On older machines like some Debian ones, this works also and is the most portable solution.

```
mv /usr/bin/editor /usr/bin/.editor
ln -s $(which vim) /usr/bin/editor
```

Comment: No, don't mess with anything in `/usr/bin` manually; these locations are managed by `dpkg` and should not be manipulated directly.