# Set default editor for crontab -e invoked with sudo

Tags: linux, vim, sudo, text-editors, crontab

I'm using Bash on Debian Squeeze. I just read this topic: [change default text editor for crontab to vim](https://superuser.com/questions/281617/change-default-text-editor-for-crontab-to-vim)

I have exported both variables `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` to vim for normal user and for root. And this works – when I type `crontab -e` as normal user or root, crontab runs vim for editing.

But running `sudo crontab -e` opens nano.

Running `sudo echo $EDITOR` (or `$VISUAL`) gave `vim` int output.

Comment: You'll find an explanation of why `sudo echo $EDITOR` doesn't do what you think it does [here](http://superuser.com/questions/493906/why-sudo-curl-ignores-proxy-settings) (and things to try to make your crontab work)

Comment: @mat: Your comment could probably be a regular answer.

Comment: Did you run 'update-alternatives --config editor' while you are root?

Comment: @tumiki: I just checked, it's work, but I'm searching solution for other (non-debian) distros too.

Answer (score 9):

By default and for security purposes, `sudo` does not preserve the user environment.

There are multiple ways to deal with this; for your specific case, I recommend adding `VISUAL=/usr/bin/vim` (and `EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim` for programs that use the wrong one) to `/etc/environment`.

Second choice, if you have a permissive sudo configuration (perhaps because it's just you, or all sudoers have real root access anyway) is to run `visudo` and add `Defaults env_keep="VISUAL EDITOR"` to allow all sudoers to specify their own (i.e. preserve that environment variable).

Your existing sudoers file may well already have (or include) one or more env_keep statement(s), e.g. this (from the pastebin example):

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"
```

The first of those `env_keep` lines will overwrite whatever edits you make above it (assignment), the other lines extend the list (`+=`). To keep everything working the way you're used to and unless you have a reason to change the set, I recommend adding a line immediately **after** those:

```
Defaults    env_keep += "VISUAL EDITOR"
```

(There are other options to use your preferred editor, but they're either needlessly complicated or overly permissive and dangerous, so you'll have to read `man sudoers`, figure them out yourself, and understand what the associated problems might be.)

Comment: Love this... except that visudo will launch vi... the thing we're trying to avoid like the plague. sudo env EDITOR=nano visudo is the way to go. Or maybe cat, which is a bit more dangerous. Also, `Defaults env_keep="VISUAL EDITOR"` only works after env reset, so putting it at the top will not work... the bottom is safest.

Comment: I am baffled by why placing env_keep="VISUAL EDITOR" under env_reset does not work... Ive only tried on top, under env_reset and at the bottom. only at the bottom works.

Comment: Without any other information, I'll just guess that there already is a line setting env_keep in the file somewhere, which overrides whatever you put in above and which you override by moving your directive to the end.

If you paste your sudoers file to pastebin.com or something and add a link here, I can extract the relevant info into the answer.

Comment: it is the default centos sudoers that gives me troubles. I should probably script that. http://pastebin.com/4s3CiVYJ

Comment: instead of editing your `sudoers` file with `visudo` the recommended approach is to create an include with `sudo vim /etc/sudoers.d/02-editor` and add the `env_keep` line there. This way you'll avoid conflicts on package upgrades and can easier maintain and sync your config files (this allows to keep an unmodified sudoers file which contains `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` at the very end).

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
sudo VISUAL=vim crontab -e
```

It works for me. (Debian 10 buster)

Comment: For me this only works with EDITOR, not VISUAL and only once. I prefer the answer from @Gabe as that only needs to be done once.